# JS sum not the same answer with Math.pow()

Tags: javascript, math

I'm tearing my hair out and this is probably something really simple

I have an equation:

```
((100000 + (2400 / 0.04)) * ((1 + 0.04)**5) - (2400 / 0.04)) * 0.99
```

Google calculator gives me the answer I need, which is 133317.82

In my console this is also giving me 133317.82, which is correct

The following should be equivalent, but gives a completely different answer?

```
(100000 + (2400 / 0.04)) * (Math.pow((1 + 0.04),5) - (2400 / 0.04)) * 0.99
```

Did I mix up my brackets? Does Math.pow not work Math.pow(base, exponent) ?

Comment: Something to do with floating point numbers, maybe?  Kinda like how `0.1+0.2` in JavaScript shows `0.30000000000000004`.

Comment: In isolation, `1.04**5 === Math.pow(1.04, 5)`

Comment: `((100000 + (2400 / 0.04)) * ((1 + 0.04)**5) - (2400 / 0.04)) * 0.99` == `133317.81974016005`

Comment: Just looking at the left side, you can see you have two open parentheses in the top code and only one in the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You could take the below expression. (I removed superfluous parentheses.)

```js
console.log(((100000 + 2400 / 0.04) * Math.pow(1 + 0.04, 5) - 2400 / 0.04) * 0.99);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parenthesization differs between the two expressions:

```
((100000 + (2400 / 0.04)) * (Math.pow(1 + 0.04,5)) - (2400 / 0.04)) * 0.99
```

works correctly. Originally, the second expression didi not group the whole subexpression that's multiplied by `0.99`.

Answer (score 2):

These two expressions have different parentheses causing them to be evaluated differently.

Let's break down the common elements:

```
a = (100000 + (2400 / 0.04));
b1 = ((1 + 0.04)**5);
b2 = Math.pow((1 + 0.04),5);
c = (2400 / 0.04);
```

Using this mapping, your first expression is this:

```
(a * b1 - c) * 0.99
```

and your second is this:

```
a * (b2 - c) * 0.99
```

You should be able to see clearly with this, that in the second expression you've altered the parentheses grouping such that `c` is subtracted off of just `b2` instead of `(a * b2)`. If you fix your parentheses, the two are the same.

```js
console.log(((100000 + (2400 / 0.04)) * Math.pow(1 + 0.04, 5) - (2400 / 0.04)) * 0.99);
```